# django-webpush: not able to find user in the request object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF, and have set up the auth middleware using JWT backend.

I used a package `safwanrahman/django-webpush` which enable sending notifications, based on `VAPID`.

I got the package working with all setup in place, The API to save information is called and executed successfully. The only problem right now is that the user information is not saved. My findings say that this is because I am using DRF. The way DRF injects a user into the request is may be different from how traditional Django does. And hence the `request.user` in the view function of the package in not found.

```
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def save_info(request):
    ...

    # the request.user mostly does not exist
    web_push_form.save_or_delete(
        subscription=subscription, user=request.user,
        status_type=status_type, group_name=group_name)

    ...
```

Right now i am thinking to make a clone of the repo and make changes directly in order to debug and find the exact issue/solution. Would that work?

Comment: Are you sure that the user is logged in?

Comment: Yes the user is logged in. But mostly the problem is that the user attributes are fetched through the rest framework middleware backend. So every class extended from DRF automatically has the user in the request object. This package as a view function which is most likely extending all Django core classes like `from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST, require_GET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given package `safwanrahman/django-webpush` is not compatible with Django rest framework, As the package core classes in view use the post and http methods from the django core classes, Which cannot find the user if you have changed the authentication middleware while using DRF.

The solution to that is to import the package folder and make changes in the view such that the view function being called is inherited from the DRF core classes and hence fourth able to find the logged in user in the request object. I am still trying to understand if somehow only that class can be extended and changed. But for now this solution works for me.

Thanks.